# What is the way to download youtube Closed Captions via Youtube v3?

Tags: java, youtube-data-api

I wrote a program in Java to download Closed Captions of a Youtube video:

```
YouTube.Captions.List request = youtube.captions()
            .list("snippet", videoId).setKey(apiKey);
        CaptionListResponse response = request.execute();

        List<Caption> captions = response.getItems();

        for (Caption caption : captions) {
            CaptionSnippet snippet = caption.getSnippet();
            System.out.println("ID: " + caption.getId());
            System.out.println("Name: " + snippet.getName());
            System.out.println("Language: " + snippet.getLanguage());

            String captionID = caption.getId();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("captions"+captionID);

            YouTube.Captions.Download req = youtube.captions()
                .download(captionID).setKey(apiKey);
            req.getMediaHttpDownloader();
            req.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(output);
        }
```

But the req.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(output); call throws the following exception:

```
There was an IO error: null : 401 Unauthorized
Login Required
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why should one authorize to download Closed Captions? Especially taking into account the fact that Closed Captions are freely available through Youtube itself:

```
- "..." below the youtube player
- Open transcript
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list#auth), accessing the `Captions.list` endpoint requires the following:

> **Authorization**
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> *Scope*
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner

The [same requirement](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download#auth) applies to the `Captions.download` endpoint too.